# CloudLinux equivalent for Windows

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage, resource-management

Is there any configuration or software solutions that would provide similar resource throttling per user like CloudLinux does for Linux? We currently run game servers on Windows 2008 OS and the major problem we come across is ghost processes, or single services consuming 90% of the CPU due to badly written modifications.

The majority of services we offer are single-threaded anyways, but in some cases they do wind up consuming almost the entire machine.

As I prefer to stay with Windows due to a lot of our software requiring it, I am looking at implementing better control over resource allocation while not being forced to change the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these prior threads which give answers for Windows:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326293/setting-maximum-cpu-usage-per-process-in-windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit